# Laravel 8 | Not hitting policy method

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to define some policies in Laravel 8 which I cannot get to work, however I have the same project in Laravel 7 which seemingly works perfectly.

I am using the JSON API Specification package and it comes built in with Authorizers which allow me to run a policy on different methods.

I am trying to add a policy for the 'create' on all routes no matter what.

I have the following code:

```
public function create($type, $request)
{
    $this->authorize('create', $type);
}
```

In this context and example, `$type = 'App\Models\User'` if I do a `dd` before that line I can confirm that I am hitting that method.

Inside of my `AuthServiceProvider` I have the following:

```
public function boot()
{
    Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing(function ($modelClass) {
        return 'App\\Policies\\' . class_basename($modelClass) . 'Policy';
    });
}
```

Which as said earlier, works perfectly in another project.

The following is my policy, as you can see it's very basic.

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;

class UserPolicy
{
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If I make a constructor in the policy class I can confirm that it is getting hit and I am getting inside of the policy which is why this is confusing me so much.

I have tried changing the name of the method in case it was something clashing with the naming convention but nothing seems to agree with it.

I have tried to dump composer just as a double check but again, no luck.

Comment: is there currently an authenticated user for this request?

Comment: @lagbox no there isn't but I didn't think that mattered as there is no middleware and would still look into the policy or am I incorrect in thinking that? I have tried to remove the User from the `create` method but no luck with that either.

Comment: no authorization is based on authorizing a user that is why those methods take a User instance ... without an authenticated user it is going to not authorize anything based on how those are written ... "By default, all gates and policies automatically return false if the incoming HTTP request was not initiated by an authenticated user. "

Comment: The actual fix which I've just figured out is the method needs to be `public function create(?User $user)` so you can use a policy as a guest user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with this is that there wasn't currently an authenticated user and although specified in the method parameters a user it was still failing.

When providing a guest route, you still need to add the parameter to the method but make it optional.

```php
public function create(?User $user)
{
    // do logic here
}
```

The documentation for this can be found at the following link: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#guest-users